# Drag & drop hierarchical list using selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

Drag & drop hierarchical list using selenium webdriver in java

```
Github link: https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

Demo link:- http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/
```

I want to drag and drop hierarchical list using selenium webdriver in java . See demo link for more details.

i tried the following things:-

1. Get the source element
2. Create a div with class=dd-placeholder
3. Drag the source element and drop on the newly created div element

Error:- Not able drop the source element on newly created div element.

How can i do it. Is it possible using selenium webdriver.

```
Note: See demo link
```

Comment: isn't dragAndDrop working where source will be div element and target will be li tag?

Comment: @VivekSingh See demo correctly.At first div[class='dd-placeholder'] will be created before drop and after drop only, it creates li tag.

Comment: if am getting it right u need (for eg.) move item 6 to item 1? Is it so?

Comment: @VivekSingh I need to move element. How can i drop the source element to newly created div with class=dd-placeholder

Comment: Since the div element u r moving to is contained in a li element. Give the target as li not div. I tried it out **(if moving item 6 to item 1)** -- `source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[.='Item 6']")); target= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-id='1']"));`

Comment: Create div.dd-placeholder with child as li element(do it manually on inspect element first). Then drag any item and move it to newly created div or li element. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I found drag and drop functionality to be a little different depending on which browser you use, and I had to add an offset to the drop location to get it to work in Chrome Firefox and IE consistently.

This is a C# snippet, but java should be similar. The target in this instance is a placeholder div that I inserted with JS, just like your approach

```
Actions act = new Actions(WebDriver);
act.ClickAndHold(source);
act.MoveToElement(target);
act.MoveByOffset(0, 5); //Minimum 1 pixel offset for Chrome, 5 for IE 
act.Release(source);
act.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: I am using the same code as you followed. But can you able imitate the functionality using selenium mentioned in demo link. I can't able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This method drags and drops a webelement from a location to another using Javascript. Don't get bogged down with its javascript :). Just use the method by providing from and to parameters. Good luck!

```
public void dragAndDrop(WebElement from, WebElement to) {
    js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {\n" + "var event =document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");\n"
            + "event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);\n" + "event.dataTransfer = {\n" + "data: {},\n"
            + "setData: function (key, value) {\n" + "this.data[key] = value;\n" + "},\n"
            + "getData: function (key) {\n" + "return this.data[key];\n" + "}\n" + "};\n" + "return event;\n"
            + "}\n" + "\n" + "function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {\n"
            + "if (transferData !== undefined) {\n" + "event.dataTransfer = transferData;\n" + "}\n"
            + "if (element.dispatchEvent) {\n" + "element.dispatchEvent(event);\n"
            + "} else if (element.fireEvent) {\n" + "element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);\n" + "}\n"
            + "}\n" + "\n" + "function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {\n"
            + "var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');\n" + "dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);\n"
            + "var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');\n"
            + "dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n"
            + "var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');\n"
            + "dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent,dropEvent.dataTransfer);\n" + "}\n" + "\n"
            + "var source = arguments[0];\n" + "var destination = arguments[1];\n"
            + "simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);", from, to);

}
```